# Change PGDATA on CentOS

Tags: linux, postgresql, installation, centos, database-migration

I have recently been trying to change my data dir on my postgres instance and managed to completely butcher the thing so bad I had to start over (smaller database right now luckily exported to csv)

I tried for the life of me to use

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-setup initdb -D /my/directory/id/like/to/use
```

but for whatever reason is rejects `-D`

After establishing the database I know i can rsync my data to a new directory on my larger disk, and I know it needs to be postgres permissions only, then I change the PGDATA variable in **/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/postgresql.conf** and then restart.

But this is causing all sorts of problems

At least I thought that was the move. What am I missing?

Comment: share the error message after running   /usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-setup initdb -D /my/directory/id/like/to/use

Comment: "But this is causing all sorts of problems" - what problems, exactly?